# Homestead and Frontier Wallet Compatibility

Tags: wallets

If you have the json file and you can check the balance via etherscan or etherchain or via web3/geth it's on the "live frontier net".

Why are there so many people questioning wallet compatibility between Frontier and Homestead, are there risks with incompatibility? What changes will Homestead introduce to wallets, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your wallet keyfile remains valid, i.e., 'compatible' - but if you don't update the client you won't be able to connect with the network (until you do update, then you'll be fine).

Confusion arises because of ambiguity in the use of the term 'wallet'. To be extra clear: the 'wallet' understood as keyfile is a file stored in the datadir (see 'keystore'); the 'wallet' understood as the software-client (e.g., 'geth') is just that - a piece of software - to which the aforementioned datadir belongs, and which allows you to interact with the network (e.g., find peers, download chaindata, perform transactions, even create smart-contracts).

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update geth. Wallet is key file and pass phrase no matter what the version

Comment: Please clarify, why update geth? Lets assume you created a wallet with the early version of geth (1.2 or so), then it should be fully compatible with the latest geth version, correct? I dont think its necessary to update geth to make a wallet file compatible.